# Label an image with a selftrained model in tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm managed to train my own model in Tensorflow with following graph:

[image: my net]

In Python it looks like:

```
with tf.name_scope("Reshaping_data") as scope:
    x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, imgSize, imgSize, 1], name="inp") #(?, 48, 48, 1)

with tf.name_scope("Conv1") as scope:
    conv1 = conv2d(x, weights['wc1'], biases['bc1']) #(?, 48, 48, 32)
    conv1 = maxpool2d(conv1, k=2) #(?, 24, 24, 32)
```

... (More convolution and fully connected) ...

```
out = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['out']), biases['out'], name="out") #(?, 43)
```

I trained it with the [GTSRB Dataset](http://benchmark.ini.rub.de/?section=gtsrb&subsection=dataset) and saved the model. Now I want to label a new image with this model.
My current label.py:

```
import tensorflow as tf
checkpoint_file = tf.train.latest_checkpoint("saved_models")
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
     sess = tf.Session()
     with sess.as_default():
         saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("{}.meta".format(checkpoint_file))
         saver.restore(sess,checkpoint_file)
         inp = graph.get_operation_by_name("Reshaping_data/inp").outputs[0]
         prediction=graph.get_operation_by_name("out").outputs[0]
         input_img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(tf.read_file("/home/DB/GTSRB/Test/00021/07406.jpg"), channels=3)
         reshaped_image = tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(tf.cast(input_img, tf.float32), 48, 48)
         float_image = tf.image.per_image_standardization(reshaped_image)
         images = tf.expand_dims(float_image, 0)
         print(sess.run(prediction,feed_dict={inp:images}))
```

But it fails when reading the feed_dict. What am I doing wrong?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "label.py", line 23, in <module>
    print(sess.run(prediction,feed_dict={inp:images}))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 767, in run
run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 925, in _run
    raise TypeError('The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. '
 TypeError: The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. Acceptable feed values include Python scalars, strings, lists, or numpy ndarrays.
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: The error you are getting is descriptive enough. You can not feed a tf.Tensor object. You have to convert the images variable to one of the valid types, for example numpy array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it like this:

```
checkpoint_file = tf.train.latest_checkpoint("saved_models")
imgSize = 48

graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
     sess = tf.Session()
     with sess.as_default():
         saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("{}.meta".format(checkpoint_file))
         saver.restore(sess,checkpoint_file)
         inp = graph.get_operation_by_name("Reshaping_data/inp").outputs[0]
         prediction=graph.get_operation_by_name("out").outputs[0]

         img = imread(imagepath, flatten=True)
         img = imresize(img, [imgSize, imgSize])
         img = img.astype('float32')

         img_mean = np.mean(img)
         img_var = np.std(img)
         img = (img - img_mean)/img_var

         #img = (48, 48)
         img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=2)
         #img = (48, 48, 1)
         img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
         #img = (1, 48, 48, 1)

         #inp expects (?, 48, 48, 1)
         res = sess.run(prediction,feed_dict={inp:img})
         print(res)
         print(res.argmax(axis=1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow is throwing an error because a Tensor/op is being passed into `feed_dict`. If you `print images` you'll notice that you don't see a numpy array but a tensor, which generally are not calculated until the session run time. Anything you pass into a `feed_dict` needs to be known, e.g. "Python scalars, strings, lists, or numpy ndarrays" as mentioned by the error, which in your case will be a numpy ndarray.

Instead of using tensorflow to read the image and reshape it, try using an `imread` function from scipy, matplotlib  or opencv and then numpy to reshape.

Comment: Doing `.eval()` or `sess.run(images)` will evaluate the tensor. There is not need to read the images with additional packages.